# Using AppEngine's DatastoreService in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to make a simple Android app that writes, for example, an entity with a key called "Example" and a value of "Hello World". Following the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/add_module?hl=en) I've created and uploaded a backend and got the basic functionality detailed there to work using the Java Servlet module, but it wouldn't save any entity on the datastore (but rather just make a toast on the client app) so it was useless for my purposes.

So now I'm trying to import the DatastoreService and Entity classes so I could use the method DatastoreService.put(Entity). However, conflicting resources on the internet and myself being unable to find a coherent guide about this process caused multiple compile errors:

Adding the following dependencies to build.gradle (app):

```
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.1'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.1'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.1'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
```

Raises the error:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'appengineSdk()'
```

Adding the following dependency to build.gradle (project):

```
classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.3'
```

And applying the plugin in the same file:

```
apply plugin: 'appengine'
```

Raises:

```
Error: Task with name 'assemble' not found in root project
```

I'm looking for clear instructions on how to properly implement the appropriate classes and handle the process as I'm very new to this aspect of Android Studio and it seems I've gone off-track. Thanks for your support.

Comment: you can try the example listed here http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/